# How can I change a specific category Big Cartel product page.

Tags: pagination, bigcartel

Big Cartel custom site...

I need to grab images from only one category because I need to change the background and add an additional banner. However, I cannot only pull from one category. If I change the products page it changes all the paginated pages. I only want to change one categories content. Anyone successful in doing this?? I think I just need to paginate from the category but I'm not sure what path to pull from. The current paginate is paginate.current I have tried replace current with several things and get a liquid error.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to target a specific category page, you can add this code to Customize Design > Advanced > Layout:

```
{% if page.full_path contains '/category/accessories' %}
  insert your code here
{% endif %}
```